# NestJS, try to use ormconfig.ts, it broke everything

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I tried to use ormconfig.json in order to follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sNosL578ECo&t=1657s) and I encountered several errors.

Firstly: I create the ormconfig.ts file in the root as in the tutorial, I run the project and I get an error telling me that I can't use "import" outside of a module.

Second: According to what I read on the forums, I change the "type" to "module" in package.json and the "module" to "ES2015" to be able to use the import.

It doesn't work, apparently I have to add "moduleResolution" to "node".

It still doesn't work.

Third: I resign to use ormconfig.json instead, remove all my changes and go back to the base but everything is still broken. Currently I have an error telling me that "exports is not defined" in /dist/main.js

Answer (score 0):

```
     ormconfig.ts
```

When your app starts, the expectation is we run only javascript code. Nest js transpiles all the code to dist/ and run javascript code.

However when your app starts up Typeorm will look for ormconfig.ts and execute it, but at that point, Nestjs is already done transpiling .ts files. Typeorm will execute .ts file as though it is a .js file that is why you are getting error.

Instead create `ormconifg.js` and use plain javascript. instead of `export`

```
     module.exports={}
```

Now you will get "Cannot use import statement outside a module". Because you are providing entities which are .ts files. Remember this file gets executed after we transpiled everything  into plain js. the solution is to import entities from .ts files, go into the dist folder and get the transpiled version of the all of the entity files.

```
  entities:['**/*.entity.js']
```

But this setting will break your test environment. in test environment, nest uses "ts-jest-transformer" which allows us somehow directly execute a ts file. it loads the ts and immediately converts into js and then executes the result. now if we set `ormconfig.js`, in test environment this file will get executed by "ts-jest-transformer" but we are not allowed to execute .js file. we have to tell jest, if u see a .js file just go ahead and execute it.  add this into tsconfig.json file

```
        allowJs:true
```

The issue will continue :) Becasue since you set `tyormconfig.s`, you loaded entities from `dist/` which are .js files. So depending in our environment we either load entities from .ts or .js files.

```
entities:process.env.NODE_ENV==='development' 
                               ? ['**/*.entity.js']
                               : ['**/*.entity.ts']
```